# matrix addition (get matrix names from string)

Tags: c

I'm trying to make matrix addition function, but the problem is not the addition. the problem is in the string, use input command and I've to check if everything alright. For matrix addition, I need to get 3 matrices names for the input.

I made an algorithm that finds the names, another function that checks the matrix name if defined and save as 'matInd'. I've saved all matInd in an array. now I need to call the add_mat function to make the manipulation, but the add_mat function must get 3 arguments: double add_mat(double MAT1[N][N], double MAT2[N][N], double MAT3[N][N])

now I don't know how to change the matInd to the Matrix name to call the function.

maybe I need to do it in another way?

**mat.h:**

```c
/* Data Structure */
typedef double mat[N][N];
```

Matrix names: MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C, MAT_D, MAT_E, MAT_F

**mymat.c:**

```c
/* Declare matrix and initialize to zero */
mat MAT_A = {0}, MAT_B = {0}, MAT_C = {0}, MAT_D = {0}, MAT_E = {0}, MAT_F = {0};
```

```c
            case ADD_MAT:
                printf("add mat..\n");
                int i = 0;
                index = skip_white_char(command, index, commandLen);
                if(is_comma(command[index])){
                    print_error(ILLEGAL_COMMA);
                    continue;
                }
                if(command[index]=='\n'){
                    print_error(MISS_PARAM);
                    continue;
                }

                clear_word(nextWord, MAX_WORD_LEN); /* Clear last word from nextWord */
                index = get_word(command, nextWord, index);
                matInd = which_mat(nextWord); /* Save the index of chosen mat */
                if(matInd == UNKNOWN_MAT){
                    print_error(UNDEF_MAT_NAME);
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    printf("%d ", matInd);
                    matrixMan[i++] = matInd;
                }

                while(is_comma(command[index])){
                    index++;
                    index = skip_white_char(command, index, commandLen);
                    if(is_comma(command[index])){
                        print_error(ILLEGAL_COMMA);
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(command[index]=='\n'){
                        print_error(MISS_PARAM);
                        continue;
                    }
                    clear_word(nextWord, MAX_WORD_LEN); /* Clear last word from nextWord */
                    index = get_word(command, nextWord, index);
                    matInd = which_mat(nextWord); /* Save the index of chosen mat */
                    if(matInd == UNKNOWN_MAT){
                        print_error(UNDEF_MAT_NAME);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        matrixMan[i++] = matInd;
                    }
                    index = skip_white_char(command, index, commandLen);
                }
                if(command[index]!='\n'){ /* There is parameters without comma between */
                    return MISS_COMMA;
                }

                continue;
```

Comment: I will move while loop to its own function later, now I just want it to work.
what do you mean change index to a string?

Comment: Variable names only exist for the programmer. They do not exist for the user, they do not exist in the generated machine code.

Comment: Btw it is bad practice to hide arrays of pointers behind typedefs. If you need custom types, use `struct` instead.

Comment: About having small enough functions: you use them so you can get your code to work (avoid and find bugs). Refactoring *after* fixing bugs kinda defeats the purpose (or half of it, other half being future maintainability, but I have a feeling this is learning code which won't be maintained in future, so...).

Comment: @Lundin what do you mean bad practice to hide?

Comment: It is not obvious to a C programmer that `mat m` declares an array, so therefore it is bad practice to use typedefs like this.